# how to delete contents from input box

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner with JavaScript.What should i do to delete the contents from my input box.This is my code,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter your name....</p>
<input id="myInput"/>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">submit</button>
<div id="result"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    var input=document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='U sure '+input+' is your name';
    myInput="";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry the previous code was not clear,Please check this,

Comment: function myFunction(){
var input=document.getElementById("myInput").value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='U sure '+input+' is your name';
myInput="";
}            where "myInput" is the id of my input box.even after refreshing the page whatever i entered remians in the input box.what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Coz you're a beginner with Javascript, I would recommend using Jquery. it would change your life-of-crossbrowser-issues to heaven (for future reference :) ).

Javascript :

```
document.getElementById("myInput").value = '';
```

Jquery :

```
$('#myInput').val('');
```

Comment: NO! I absolutely have to disagree with this kind of answer! If someone's beginner with javascript, the worst thing is to learn jQuery. You firstly MUST lear javascript, and then try to look at and understand js frameworks/libraries :)

Comment: It can go both ways. Depends if the user wants to create libraries etc. or just do basic front-end manipulation...then jQuery would be perfect. Just a suggestion.

Comment: well, at least Marc show both methods. I agree that indhu should pick up JQuery somehow.

Comment: Yh, a general jQuery suggestion could be good, but this "Coz you're a beginner with Javascript, I would recommend using Jquery" is totally wrong. ;) (sorry for the typo in my prev comment '..firstly MUST learn...')

Comment: Thanks, the base reason I said it was because of the cross browser issues we all experienced over the past decade, and the ease of use. But all depends from user to user and what they want to achieve. :) But thanks anyway, I will keep your comment in mind for next time. :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check out jQuery after you know the basics about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";